# React bootstrap modal doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

Cant make my modal works. Everything seems set up.
Can somebody help me? It must be something trivial
because [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jb3okt?file=index.js)
similar set up and it works. Its like my bootstrap is not loaded
from index.html.

I have in index.html my bootstrap js and css.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Home from './Home';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import GroupList from './GroupList';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact={true} component={Home}/>
          <Route path='/groups' exact={true} component={GroupList}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

GroupList.js where is my modal

```js
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open modal
</button>


<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't combine React with any DOM-manipulation libraries like bootstrap JS. While it works in the snippet you link to, it won't here because of your use of React router which means the modal isn't always in the DOM - I assume bootstrap sets up all the necessary event listeners when the DOM is first loaded, so won't find the button and therefore will do nothing. While I've never personally used it, the [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) library should give you React components that implement Bootstrap modals etc

Comment: I recommend [reactstrap](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap) if you are into classes more than hooks

Answer (score 0):

I would also advise you to implement "reactstrap" library. Then use state to control if the modal should be opened.